# SQL statement that returns a zero when result is either null or blank

Tags: sql

I'm trying to setup this SQL statement that will return a zero value when the query count is null or blank.

```
SELECT NAME,
       CASE
         WHEN COUNT(question1) IS NULL THEN 0
         ELSE COUNT(question1)
       END
FROM   INQUIRY2
GROUP  BY name,
          question1
HAVING Question1 = 'Yes'
       AND Name IN ( 'person1', 'person2' )
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Comment: `COUNT(question1)` can never be `NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for COALESCE, which returns the first non-null in its argument list.

```
SELECT NAME, coalesce (COUNT(question1), 0)
FROM INQUIRY2
group by name, question1
having Question1 ='Yes' 
and Name IN ('person1', 'person2')
```

In this case it doesn't seem like COUNT(question1) could be null.

Comment: For some reason this works, but I need to include the name SELECT coalesce (COUNT(question1), 0)
FROM INQUIRY2
where Question1 ='Yes' 
and Name ='person1'